# VS Code thinks closing tags are missing - but all are there

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

My VS Code thinks I have 7 missing closing tags on this component. All of them are there.

Lines that VS Code doesn't like are marked with ** - with the error message commented in italics below the relevant closing tag.

I'm looking for tips on how I find the source of the error?

Dashboard2.jsx

```
import React, {  useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'

import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import PaletteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Palette';
import CenterFocusWeakIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CenterFocusWeak';
import RoomServiceIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RoomService';
import StorefrontIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Storefront';
import AssignmentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Assignment';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import AccountBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountBox';
import ContactSupportIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ContactSupport';
import BookIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Book';
import TuneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Tune';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import DashboardFooter from "./DashboardFooter";
import Dsm from "./Dsm/Menu";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
    },
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    // autoWidth: false
    
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));

export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
 //   const { performingAction, user, userData, roles } = this.props;

  
  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
 
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
        **<AppBar** 
            position="fixed"
            className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: open,
            })}
        >
```

*//  'JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag.'*

```
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
              [classes.hide]: open,
            })}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap style={{ letterSpacing: '.5rem'}}>
            {process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE}
            
          </Typography>
            
          <IconButton color="inherit"><CloseIcon /></IconButton>    
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
            })}
            classes={{
            paper: clsx({
                [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
                [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
            }),
            }}
        >
            <div className={classes.toolbar}>
              <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                  {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <List>
            
                <ListItem button key="1" component={Link} to={"/Dsm" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><PaletteIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary="DSM"></ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="2" component={Link} to={"/MMM" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><CenterFocusWeakIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>MM</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="3" component={Link} to={"/CentreMenu" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><StorefrontIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>Centre</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="4" component={Link} to={"/ToolsMenu" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><AssignmentIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>Tools</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                <ListItem button key="5"  component={Link} to={"/Profile" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <AccountBoxIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Profile</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="6"  component={Link} to={"/Account" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <SettingsIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Account</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="7"  component={Link} to={"/Mail" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <MailIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Mail</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="8"  component={Link} to={"/Notifications" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <NotificationsIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Notifications</ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
            
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                
                <ListItem button key="9"  component={Link} to={"/KCentreMenu" }>
                    <ListItemIcon> <BookIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>KCentre</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="10"  component={Link} to={"/DeskMenu" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><RoomServiceIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>Desk</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="11"  component={Link} to={"/Support" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <ContactSupportIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Help and Support</ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
            </List>
        </Drawer>
        **<main className={classes.content}>**
          **<div className={classes.toolbar} />**

            **<Switch>**
                **<Route path="/Dsm" component={Dsm} />**
```

*//'Identifier expected.'*

```
                <Route path="/MM" component={Dsm} />
            </Switch>
```

*//'Unterminated string literal.'*

**'Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'p'.' - I think this is referring to the self closing div with the toolbar class - there is no p tag in this component**

```
        </main>
```

**// 'JSX element 'main' has no corresponding closing tag.'**

```
     </BrowserRouter>   
     
    **</div>**
   *//''</' expected.' - note this error message, pointing at this div, is reported twice*

      
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forced quit and restarted my vs code - the problems have gone now. the laptop has been hot all day. So strange.